# Can we update CUDA version 9.0 to 10.0 in docker container?

Tags: docker, cuda, gpu, nvidia-docker

I am new to docker. I am trying to run one github repository in docker container. I have few questions regarding the same.

1. The docker image was created using CUDA version 9.0. I have Tesla T4 GPU and Driver version 470.129.06 in my amazon EC2 instance. I want to update CUDA version from 9 to 10.0. Is is possible to update cuda version inside the docker container? If yes, then How do we update it? Can you share some useful links?
2. Whenever I run nvidia-docker run command it enters into fish interactive shell. I want it to start bash interactive shell. I don’t know how to enter in bash shell after running docker

The command I am running is:

```
nvidia-docker run -it --rm -v /Path_to_dataset:/root/data -v $Path_to_model:/root/model --ipc=host scrin/second-pytorch
```

I tried adding bash in command but does not work (I get error: `open: No such file or directory`).

```
nvidia-docker run -it --rm -v /Path_to_dataset:/root/data -v $Path_to_model:/root/model --ipc=host scrin/second-pytorch bash
```

The git repository I am using is: https://github.com/traveller59/second.pytorch

If anyone can help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you need to make some changes in your image's Dockerfile.  Can you [edit] the question to include the source code necessary to reproduce your issue?

Comment: I have added git repository link in the question. @DavidMaze

Comment: You need to include a [mcve], including the required source code, in the question itself and not behind a link.  (If you resolve the issue and update the GitHub repository, the link won't be especially meaningful.)  [ask] has some more tips on writing a good question.

Comment: Have you created the docker image yourself? Do you have full access to docker commands in your instance (not only running), you can copy/download bash binaries into your docker, can you manually update the CUDA version?

Comment: No, I haven't created image by myself. I am using the available image in hub.docker.com. The image I am using is "docker pull scrin/second-pytorch". I want to update CUDA manually. but not sure how to do it. @Sebastian

Comment: Perhaps try to build the image yourself. On the linked Github there is a Dockerfile https://github.com/traveller59/second.pytorch/blob/master/Dockerfile which in turn refers to the base image nvidia/cuda:9.0-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu16.04 That probably is the best start to change the CUDA version instead of updating afterwards (which you can also try, if changing the base image leads to nowhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

1.

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/10.2/Prod/local_installers/cuda_10.2.89_440.33.01_linux.run
sh cuda_10.2.89_440.33.01_linux.run
```

2. If you enter in fish shell run command `bash` then it will enter in bash interactive shell.